Reached end of template in the middle of a comment
ASP.NET project on local server is throwing this error

Reached end of template in the middle of a comment

In the config file, connection string is set up properly with database name, username and password are all correct, but IIS shows this error. Please help me with this.
I checked connection string in the web.config file.

ASP.NET (on the full/legacy .NET framework) - or ASP.NET Core on the newer, cross-platform .NET Core platform? You've tagged both ..... also: you might have checked the connection string  - we cannot, since we (a) can't read your screen, (b) can't read your mind, and (c) you haven't showed your connection string here ....

That error message looks like it comes from a Handlebars templating library - which has nothing to do with database connection-strings.

Does this error only appear when published on iis? Does your ASP.NET project work properly locally?

@samwu this error appears locally.

@Dai I think you're right the error is coming from Handlebars. So, what should I do?

@Bran Grow a moustache
